# Making Sibling elements fixed irrespective of top ones position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the code I'm having trouble with.

HTML

```
<a href="">abc</a>
<p>text</p>
```

CSS

```
a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
a:hover {
  height: 90px;
}
```

I have 2 elements and i want to make  second elements position fixed irrespective of height of first one. In above fiddle the height varies on "Hover" and then i see the second element jerking.

Using position Fixed and Absolute will not work in my case.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padding-top` for the paragraph. The value is the difference of the heights in normal and hover state. I have used `+` sibling selector to select the next element.

```css
a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
a:hover {
  height: 90px;
}
a:hover + p {
  padding-top: 10px; /* Value(Difference between heights) */
}
```

```html
<a href="">abc</a>
<p>text</p>
```